# send a specific DTMF phone as soon as hangup the call on asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I have a phone kind of remote device which will initiate a call  to asterisk . On other side I have an IP phone registered with asterisk . When the conversation is over and the person at IPPhone hangup the call , I wanted to send a specific DTMF tone ( for example * or # )  to the remote device  so that the device can be reset to on-hook state and ready to make another call .

Can someone tell me how it can be achieved . *The person at ipphone side will not press any key so i want asterisk to do that .

Comment: Why just ending call couldn't be sufficient? Also sending DTMF, even with SIP INFO, would not be 100% reliable. I would rather use session timer mechanism or RTP inactivity detection to check for session teardown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[mycontext]
exten => 123456,1,Dial(SIP/123456,,gF)
exten => 123456,n,SendDTMF(#)
```

123456 is IP phone and calls from remote device should hit context mycontext.

Comment: Hello does this send DTMF as soon as hangup the call ?. My requirement is to send the DTMF tone after hangup the call . I will test this and update here . Thankyou

Comment: This one send dtmf to caller once called party hangup.

Comment: you can use the h extension